# Mixed strategies in 3x3 game - can strategies be negative?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Heres the payoff for player one.

[image]

I'm searching for mixed strategies of player two.  However I do the algebra, i get:p=4/5, q=3/10 and z=1-p-q=-0,1.

Could anybody please explain, how negative probabilities are possible in mixed strategies, or, and I hope, where did I the error?

-p+5q+2=-2p+q+4=3p+q

results in:

-2p+q+4=3p+q
p=4/5

-(4/5)+5q+2=3(4/5)+q
q=(16/5-2)/4
q=0,3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

No, probabilities can't be negative.  If an attempt to calculate a mixed strategy produces negative numbers, it means there is no mixed strategy that does what you're attempting to get it to do.
In this case it looks like you're trying to make the first player's average payoffs for each of his three pure strategies be equal.
That can't be done.
Instead, with the mixed strategy $(4/5, 0, 1/5)$ 
the second player can ensure the first player's average payoff is at most
$12/5$ (namely the average payoff would be $6/5$ with strategy A and $12/5$ with B or C).  In a zero-sum game, this would in fact be an optimal strategy for the second player.  I obtained this by solving the linear programming problem

$$ \eqalign{\text{minimize} & \ z\cr
\text{subject to} & \ z \ge p + 7 q + 2 r\cr & z \ge 2 p + 5 q + 4 r \cr
& z \ge 3p + q\cr
& p + q + r = 1\cr
&p,q,r \ge 0             }$$

Comment: For my own curiosity, I know that in a 2x2 game, bad things might happen if we attempt to convert to a linear programming question if any entries are nonpositive and so we often modify the matrix by adding a multiple of the ones matrix first.  I notice that you allowed one of the entries to remain zero.  Does that affect the answer in this 3x3 case?

Comment: What bad things?  The only thing I can think of is if you require the payoff variable ($z$ above) to be nonnegative.  I do not require that.  Linear programming can be done perfectly well with some variables unrestricted.

Comment: Ah, I see the difference now.  When I learned the method, we used "minimize $z = p+q+r$ subject to $a_{1,i}p + a_{2,i}q + a_{3,i}r \leq 1$" whereas you have $\leq z$ and $p+q+r=1$.  Indeed they do give the same answer, just that the linear program appears in a different form.  (bad things I referred to are for example not having a feasible region to test)